# How to join together member variable values as comma separated String's from a list of objects into a member variable of another class

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Metrics class

```
public class Metrics {
    private String signal_strength = "a";
    private String tx_rate = "b";
    private String rx_rate = "c";
} 

public class Metrics {
    private String signal_strength = "d";
    private String tx_rate = "e";
    private String rx_rate = "f";
}
```

and I have a List of Metrics objects

```
List<Metrics> metricList= Arrays.asList(new Metrics[]{Metrics1,Metrics2});
```

i have to create an object of MetricCollector which should have a comma separated values from each Metric object in metricList

```
public class MetricCollector {  
    private String total_signal_strength = "a,d";
    private String total_tx_rate = "b,e";
    private String total_rx_rate = "c,f";
}
```

I could iterate over the list and use StringBuilder to acheive this but i'm looking to see using Java8 features ...  Is there a cleaner way to it

Note: I know that I have taken some syntactical liberty to explain my use-case better please excuse that.

Comment: The easiest but least efficient way is to create a stream for each field: `total_signal_strength = metricList.stream().map(m -> m.signal_strength).collect(Collectors.joining(","));`

Comment: You can make a custom collector that contains 3 `StringBuilders`, and stream the list into that collector.

Comment: @shmosel: that’s not the least efficient way to do it. There are way more expensive solutions possible. I have no idea why people are trying so hard to avoid iterating over an in-memory structure like an array…

Comment: @Holger Lol, that's a good point.